# Scriptable Image Editing Desktop Applications

Tags: software-recommendation, batch-processing

PhotoShop and (IIRC) FireWorks both allow for batch processing of images following a recorded script. Are there other desktop image editing applications I could look at that also have that same capability? Open source or pay. MacOS or Windows (Or Ubuntu, for that matter).

I am primarily looking for an easy way to batch resize collections of images. Ideally, I could auto-crop as well (crop canvas to maximum image size).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I have to just batch resize images I would use either [**Automator**](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2488) (OS X) or [**IrfanView**](http://www.irfanview.com/) (Windows)

If I'd like to use command line, I'd use [**sips**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html), [**ImageMagick**](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or [**NConvert**](http://www.xnview.com/en/nconvert.html).

Also [**GIMP**](http://www.gimp.org/) has scripting powers and also can be used via [command line](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/).

Comment: Automator! I've never used it. And feel rather silly for not have in the past. Looks like Pixelmator can be scripted with that. Will definitely play with that!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @koiyu's response, [Acorn by Flying Meat Software](http://flyingmeat.com/acorn/) has robust yet simple-to-use scripting capabilities.

Comment: Good one. Possibility that an app has scripting (or at least batching) capabilities steeply rise if you have to throw some money at it.

Comment: Looks like it also uses Automator. Nice. Has anyone used both Acorn and Pixelmator? Any thoughts on a comparison?